# I have problem with FBSDK in my react-native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I have a problem.

```
 "#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h>"
```

I see this string  in file FBSDKCoreKit.h, but file FBSDKAppEvents.h is not here. Real path is FBSDKCoreKit/AppEvents/FBSDKAppEvents.h 
Similar errors with other files FBSDKAppEvents... and FBSDKAppLink...
Its new error - in old versions all files were in one dir. 
What to do?

Comment: You may need to change the Header Search Paths in Xcode